# Como saber si el valor de una columna se encuentra dentro de una lista que tengo?

Tags: python, lista

Buenas tengo la siguiente lista:

```
milista = [' 5093', ' 5243', ' 5390', ' 5753', ' 5818', ' 5961', ' 5966', ' 6016', ' 6256']
```

como puedo saber si mi columna.value == algun elemento de milista:

```
import openpyxl
doc = openpyxl.load_workbook("archivo.xlsx")
hoja = doc['Hoja1']
for fila in hoja.rows:
    for columna in fila:
        if columna.value == ALGUN ELEMENTO DENTRO DE LA LISTA "milista":
            print(columna.value)
```

Comment: `if columna.value in milista`

Comment: Gracias @abulafia, y es posible que se imprima en el orden que esta en la lista y no en el valor de la columna?

Comment: `for i in milista: if i in columna.value: print(i)` ???
Dentro del bucle `for columna in fila:`.